# Error - Posting to aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I am new on AWS. I was trying to do an http post to an aws lambda function and received an error 403(Forbidden). I understood I had to pass AWS_SECRET and AWS_Key with post. How do I do it? My coding language for post is golang.

**Code in Context**

```
url := "https://xxxxx.xxxxx-api.us-west-x.amazonaws.com/prod/xxxxxx"
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"title":"Some data"}`)

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))

req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status) // response message
```

**Respose Message**

> response Status: 403 Forbidden

How should I pass the authentication parameters? Is it to be passed along with the url?

Comment: To be clear, you are posting at an API Gateway endpoint which is backed by a lambda function? The issue is with the api configuration. I'm guessing the X-Custom-Header there is part of your API authorization? I'd look to double check that side of things.

Comment: @stevepkr84 can you please explain how to send the params?

Answer (score 1):

How you invoke a Lambda function over HTTP via API Gateway very much depends on how the API Gateway is configured.

By default there is no authentication, so plain POST might work:

```
$ curl -X POST https://x19vpdk568.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/users -d '{"username":"noah"}'
{
  "id": "4c47648f-e419-456b-97b8-22f82a9df6cb",
  "username": "noah"
}
```

Check out my [HTTP Functions with API Gateway and Lambda](https://github.com/nzoschke/gofaas/blob/master/docs/http-functions.md) guide for tips on setting this simple configuration up.

You can [configure API Gateway to use IAM for authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html), which requires the AWS access key and secret. In this case, you have follow the [AWS Signature V4 authentication scheme](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html). There is a [v4 signer package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/signer/v4/) in the aws-sdk-go which can help.

Finally, you can also configure [API Gateway custom authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) to require a custom header, etc. These schemes don't need AWS access keys.

All said, take a close look at your API Gateway configuration to get your POST working.